# How do I add a legend to my KML so that it does not move

Tags: kml

I want to add a legend to my KML that will always be in the same location no matter where you  are on the map. How do you do this? An overlay or something?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a static legend using a Screen Overlay (although you will need to create the image that is being used manually).  Here are links to relevant documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#screen_overlays
- https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#screenoverlay